# Python - How to use re.finditer with multiple patterns

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, findall

I want to search 3 Words in a String and put them in a List
something like:

`sentence = "Tom once got a bike which he had left outside in the rain so it got rusty"`

`pattern = ['had', 'which', 'got' ]`

and the answer should look like:
`['got', 'which','had','got']`
I haven't found a way to use `re.finditer` in such a way. Sadly im required to use `finditer`
rather that `findall`

Comment: Then why you tagged findall?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the pattern from your list of searched words, then build your output list with a list comprehension from the matches returned by `finditer`:

```
import re

sentence = "Tom once got a bike which he had left outside in the rain so it got rusty"

pattern = ['had', 'which', 'got' ]
regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(pattern) + r')\b')
# the regex will be r'\b(had|which|got)\b'

out = [m.group() for m in regex.finditer(sentence)]
print(out)

# ['got', 'which', 'had', 'got']
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to combine the entries of the *pattern* list to form a regular expression with ***or***s.
Then, you can use the following code fragment:

```
import re

sentence = 'Tom once got a bike which he had left outside in the rain so it got rusty. ' \
           'Luckily, Margot and Chad saved money for him to buy a new one.'

pattern = ['had', 'which', 'got']

regex = re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(pattern)))
# regex = re.compile(r'\b(had|which|got)\b')

results = [match.group(1) for match in regex.finditer(sentence)]

print(results)
```

The result is `['got', 'which', 'had', 'got']`.

Comment: Your regex would also match the 'got' in 'Margot' and 'had' in 'Chad'

Comment: Thanks, I incorporated your hint.